# Disable system settings change on android or monitor changes on it

Tags: android, settings, system

I'm developing an device manager application, which will be set as system application.

for security reasons, I want to have the option to disable changing system settings.

Also when it is enabled I need to monitor changes in the system settings.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Although I don't know how you can actually do that, I am sure that:

 
 - The device which is running the app must be rooted
 
 - Your app should have root permissions

Comment: My device also have root permission